# Javascript array return is adding double quotes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
function iLoveThree (array) {
  var threes = [];
  var x;
  for (x in array) {
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
      threes.push(x)
    }
  }
  return threes
}
```

When I pass the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] I get the following:

```
Function returned 
["0","3","6"]
instead of 
[3,6,9]
```

My question is, where are these double quotes coming from?

Comment: Better don't use `for...in` to iterate arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for..in` loop does *not* loop through the array elements, it loops through the indices of the array.  So for:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
for ( x in arr ) console.log( x );
```

You'll get the string keys of `["0", "1", "2"]`

You can fix your code by replacing your loop with a native `for` loop:

```
for ( var x = 0; x < array.length; x++ ) {
    if (array[i] % 3 == 0)
        threes.push(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I had almost the same exact code earlier but I was using array[count] instead of a variable. Which is what @void said in his comment above.

Comment: Crockford has recommended `array.forEach` over the traditional `for` loop. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 2):

`for...in` is a bad way of iterating array indices. Better use `filter`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].filter(function(x) {
  return x % 3 == 0;
}); // [3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Can you tell me why `for...in` is bad? Douglas Crockford also doesnt recommend it, I cant recall why though.

Comment: @RahulDesai See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630). In this case `for...in` would be problematic because it does not guarantee any order, so the result would beimplementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

So basically in `x in array` `x` is the index not the array value. Because anyway `0` is not in the array but your function is returning it as well. You should instead access the values using `array[x]`

There are various approaches, one of them is using `.filter`

```
function iLoveThree(array){
    return array.filter(function(x){
        return (x%3==0?1:0);
    });
}
```

Or

```
function iLoveThree (array) {
  var threes = [];
  var x;
  [].forEach.call(array, function(x){
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
      threes.push(x)
    }
  }
  return threes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop which gives you the keys in an object, or in this case and array. Keys are always strings. Instead, you want to use a standard `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var x = array[i];
  if (x % 3 === 0) {
    threes.push(x);
  }
}
```

Or if you want to use a more functional approach, you could use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
return array.filter(function(x) {
  return x % 3 === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are pushing in the indexes and not the actual values, go ahead and try the following:

```
function iLoveThree(array) {
    var threes = [];
    var x;
    for (x in array) {
        if (((x-2) % 3) == 0) {
            threes.push(array[x])
        }
    }
    return threes;
}
```

Another option, shorter, is:

```
function iLoveThree(arr) {
    var threes = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i = i + 3) {
        threes.push(arr[i]);
    };
    return threes;
}
```

if you are comfortable with callback/predicate based loops, you could make stuff even shorter by filtering the array, instead of creating a new one:

```
function iLoveThree(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(x) {
        return (x % 3) == 0;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question directly, but here's a nice way to pull every multiple of 3 from an array of numbers:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].filter(item => item % 3 === 0)`

Comment: Note that arrow functions don't work in most browsers without transpiling.

Comment: @TbWill4321 The question didn't specify the JS version.

Answer (score 0):

Before you read the answer below, please read: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) (Thanks to @Oriol for this link.)

Douglas Crockford has also discouraged the use of `for..in`. He recommends using `array.forEach` instead.

```js
function iLoveThree (array) {
  var threes = [];

  array.forEach(function(item, i){  // use forEach, 'item' is the actual value and 'i' is the index
    if (item % 3 === 0) {
      threes.push(item); // you missed ; here
    }
  });

  return threes;  // you missed ; here
}

console.log(iLoveThree([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]));
```

Read up: [`Array.prototype.forEach()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score -1):

If you read the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) documentation, you will realize that you are pushing to `threes` the **indexes** (also called **keys**) not the **values**, because the variable `x` represents the index, so the value should be accessed by `array[x]`.

```
function iLoveThree (array) {
  var threes = [];

  for (var x in array) {
    if (array[x] % 3 == 0) {
      threes.push(array[x])
    }
  }
  return threes
}
```

There are several ways to achieve this, the best one is by using a `filter`, but that way was already explained by someone else, therefore I will use an exotic implementation using a `reduce`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].reduce(function(acc, e){return e % 3 == 0 ? acc.concat(e) : acc}, [])
```

Outputs `3, 6, 9`

Comment: This still gives him an incorrect answer.  He wants the values that are divisible by three, not the indices.

Comment: @TbWill4321 Solved, I was editing it, when you commented! But thanks